# Django postgres : Is their any way to reference jsonfield of one model into another?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I have a jsonfoeld in a model now I want to use that jsonfield into another model . Is their any way to referrence jsonfield of one model into another? 
If not ,can anyone suggest a better way to do that?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to reference fields. You can do one of the following

1. Create foreign key relationship between the models, and then refer to the json field by referring to the related model.
2. Create a json field on the new model, and do a data migration to store the data in the new model.

Comment: OK thanks.If I use foreignkey then all the fields of model1 will be referred or only primary key?

Comment: all keys will be available. please upvote if you found the answer useful

Comment: yeah basically I can refer all filed of model1 into model2 right?

Comment: that's correct. you can do model2_obj.model1_fk.field to access all fields

Comment: The [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) are the best place